# Trying to understand difference between map and flatMap output in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

for code with flatMap

```
let scoresByName = ["Henk": [0, 5, 8], "John": [2, 5, 8]]

let flatMap = scoresByName.flatMap {
    $0.key
}

print(flatMap)
```

o/p is ["J", "o", "h", "n", "H", "e", "n", "k"]

and for code using map

```
let scoresByName = ["Henk": [0, 5, 8], "John": [2, 5, 8]]

let flatMap = scoresByName.map {
    $0.key
}
```

o/p is ["John", "Henk"]

why flatMap is splitting the keys "Henk" and "John" into characters?

Comment: String is a collection of characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/flatmap(_:)-jo2y) is "map, and then flatten." "Flatten" means to turn a Sequence of Sequences in an single Array containing all the elements. `[ [1,2], [3,4] ]` becomes `[1,2,3,4]`.

So the first step is the output of `map`, which is `["John", "Henk"]`. Each of those [Strings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string#) is a Sequence of Character, so flatten merges that into a single Array of Character.